# Angular / Karma - $http.get not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, angular-mock, karma-mocha

I have an AngularJS project which uses Karma to run some unit tests in the browser. I'm using mocha as the test framework.

However, I've got some specification tests which need to read some JSON files and check that they adhere to a given convention spec (types, name convention etc).

I should make it clear that it is the actual contents of these files that I want to test. Not a spoofed version of them through Angular Mock's `$httpBackend`.

I'm marking the JSON files for serving in `karma.conf.js`.

```
files: [
  { pattern: 'static/assets/json/cards/*.json', included: false, served: true },
  'path/to/angular.js',
  'path/to/angular-mocks.js',
  'tests/**/*.js'
]
```

If I run `karma start`, I can browse over to `/base/static/assets/json/cards/something.json` and see that the files are being served.

Next, in my test, both the `$http` and the `$q` services are injected.

```
var $http, $q;

beforeEach(module('chai'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_$http_, _$q_) {
  $http = _$http_;
  $q = _$q_;
}));
```

Then I try to load each resource using `$http.get`. Finally, the promises returned from `$http.get` are collated and a call to `$q.all` is made in order to wait for them all to be done, before calling `done()` and moving on.

```
it('should load the resources', function(done) {
  var promises = ['admissions.json', 'discharge.json']
  .map(function(resource) {
    console.log('Loading', resource);
    return $http.get('/base/static/assets/json/cards/' + resource);
  });

  $q.all(promises)
  .then(function(card) {
    console.log('Success');
    done();
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Failure', err);
    done();
  });
});
```

When my tests run, I see following console output:

```
Loading admissions.json
Loading discharge.json
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

At first I assumed that it might have been exceeding the timeout by taking a long time to load, but the file is only 95kb.

Next, I wondered whether the custom promise interface (`.success` and `.error`) for `$http` was breaking the `$q.all` method. But apparently not.

Finally I tried to make a standalone request for `/base/static/assets/json/cards/admissions.json` at the beginning of all the tests.

It returns a promise, as expected, but it is never resolved, because no response is sent back. I checked the network tools to see what was coming back and it turns out that the request isn't even made in the first place. The code definitely runs, but for some reason `$http` doesn't actually make the request.

My inclination is that this is something to do with Angular Mocks intercepting `$http` requests for it's own `$httpBackend` service. How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in [this blog](http://brianmcd.com/2014/03/27/a-tip-for-angular-unit-tests-with-promises.html). The problem it's that you have to add the digest of the scope, even if you are not testing controllers.

```
it('does a thing one way', function() {
    var value;
    deferred.promise.then(function(_value_) {
        value = _value_;
    });
    deferred.resolve(10);
    expect(value).not. toBe(10); // not yet 10 because $digest hasn't run
    $scope.$digest();
    expect(value).toBe(10); // 10 because $digest already ran
});
```